# How to stop poll() from being interrupted by a specific signal

Tags: c, linux, timer, signals

I have a C application using poll to wait for some data.

Currently I am implementing the rest of my application into this one and I use time based interrupts (SIGRTMIN). As expected poll() returns if one of my other timers call back.

How can I stop poll from doing that? I am reading a lot about ppoll(), but not sure how to use that... Can I use this to stop this function from returning when a timer event is fired?

(I do not have any problems with the poll being delayed a few ms)

Comment: Use `sigprocmask()` (or `pthread_sigmask()`, for a multi-threaded program) to find the current signal-mask, `sigaddset()` the signal you want to block for the duration of the `[p]poll()`, then either pass the signal-mask to `ppoll()`, or `sigprocmask()/pthread_sigmask()` before calling `poll()`, and accept that there will be a race-condition.

Answer (score 4):

If a thread / process blocking in `poll()` receives an unblocked signal then `poll()` *will* be interrupted.  If you don't want that to happen then you can block the desired signal before calling `poll()`, and then unblock it after `poll()` returns (see `sigprocmask()`).  Note, however, that that won't cause `poll()` to be delayed -- quite the opposite.  If anything, it will cause receipt of the signal to be delayed.  If `poll()` blocks long enough then it could cause multiple RT signals to queue up, so that after you unblock that signal you receive it multiple times in quick succession.

You should consider instead checking `poll()`'s return value (which you should always do anyway) and retrying if it is `EINTR`.

Comment: As the use of signal masking will mask for the whole application, so the other timers won't interrupt either, I decided to put a while around the poll and added a set of timers around it. I get the timestamp before the while, and in the while I get another timestamp. If the difference between these timers is over the timeout given to the poll, I break out of the while, as well as if the poll that has been canceled and there is something available (POLLIN).

Comment: Does the poll handler in userspace is done in interrupt context ?